# Drools Global Logger in DRL - Illegal class for global

Tags: drools, kie, drools-kie-server, kie-server

I am trying to pass an slf4j Logger object to my Drools rule as a global.

In my calling Java class I define the logger and pass it to the rule via the setGlobal kie server command:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KieServerTester.class);

Command<?> setGlobalCommand = commandsFactory.newSetGlobal("logger", LOGGER);
    commands.add(setGlobalCommand);
```

And in my rule file I have the global defined as:

```
global org.slf4j.Logger logger;
```

However when I execute the command I get this error:

> ERROR [org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieContainerCommandServiceImpl] (default task-1) Error calling container 'mycontainer': java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal class for global. Expected [org.slf4j.Logger], found [java.util.LinkedHashMap].

I have no idea where it's getting LinkedHashMap from. I have stepped through the calling code but can't see where the map appears.

If I change my global in the rule file to be a LinkedHashMap, I don't get the error.
So somehow it looks like my logger object in the Java class is being converted to a LinkedHashMap.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass whatever object you want to a Kie-Server. I assume you are using REST to communicate with the Kie-Server, and in that case, objects have to be serialized at your end and deserialized at the Kie-Server's end.
I guess that the Kie-Server can't deserialize the object you are passing, and it is just leaving it as a `Map`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: From what I have read slf4j loggers can be serialized (although they do not implement Serializable, so perhaps that is the issue). However I have read several sources showing that it should be possible to pass an sl4fj logger to rules. Is the issue here that I am using KIE server rather than setting the global via KIE session?

Comment: Do you have the Logger class in the Kie server classpath?